# How to convert a string with one backslash to three backslashes

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to convert this string with one backslah:

```
"{\"PartyCode\":\"99\",\"Name\":\"ooooo\",\"NameEng\":null,\"Note\":null,\"ManagerId\":1,\ParentId\":null,\"PartyStatusId\":1,\"PartyTypeId\":1,\"CenterInfoId\":4177,\"GovernateInfoId\":321,\"LocationInfoId\":25,\"SectorInfoId\":6,\"SectorGroupInfoId\":36,\"SectorCategroyInfoId\":66,\"MainBranch\":null,\"CoordinateX\":null,\"CoordinateY\":null,\"IssueDate\":\"2022-06-08T00: 00:00\"}"
```

To this string with 3 backslashes:

```
 "{\\\"PartyCode\\\":\\\"99\\\",\\\"Name\\\":\\\"ooooo\\\",\\\"NameEng\\\":null,\\\"Note\\\":null,\\\"ManagerId\\\":1,\\\"ParentId\\\":null,\\\"PartyStatusId\\\":1,\\\"PartyTypeId\\\":1,\\\"CenterInfoId\\\":4177,\\\"GovernateInfoId\\\":321,\\\"LocationInfoId\\\":25,\\\"SectorInfoId\\\":6,\\\"SectorGroupInfoId\\\":36,\\\"SectorCategroyInfoId\\\":66,\\\"MainBranch\\\":null,\\\"CoordinateX\\\":null,\\\"CoordinateY\\\":null,\\\"IssueDate\\\":\\\"2022-06-08T00: 00:00\\\"}"
```

I tried `.Replace("\\","\\\\\\")` but did not work.

Comment: That string doesn't contain any backslashes, those are just there to escape the double quotes (apart from one missing in the middle). To be honest, this question seems to be an XY problem, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidG i want to send this json to a service, but the service does not work without the json with 3 backslahes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your original string is escaping the double quotes.

Your desired string is escaping the double quotes, and adding an escaped backslash preceeding the double quotes.

So to get your desired string, you need to ensure that you preceed every double quote with a backslash.

You could do that with `.Replace(@"""", @"\""")`.

Also note that your original string is missing a double quote before ParentId.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoyed

```
    //classical
    string input = "{\"PartyCode\":\"99\",\"Name\":\"ooooo\",\"NameEng\":null,\"Note\":null,\"ManagerId\":1,\"ParentId\":null,\"PartyStatusId\":1,\"PartyTypeId\":1,\"CenterInfoId\":4177,\"GovernateInfoId\":321,\"LocationInfoId\":25,\"SectorInfoId\":6,\"SectorGroupInfoId\":36,\"SectorCategroyInfoId\":66,\"MainBranch\":null,\"CoordinateX\":null,\"CoordinateY\":null,\"IssueDate\":\"2022-06-08T00: 00:00\"}";
    string output = input.Replace("\"", @"\\\""");
    Console.WriteLine(output);

    //or extreme something like this
    StringBuilder output2 = new StringBuilder();
    input.Select(x=> {
        if (x.ToString() == "\"")
            output2.Append(@"\\\""");    
        else 
            output2.Append(x);
        return x;
    }).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(output2.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

The string is immutable creates a new string each time. So you have to reassign new string to the previous variable. Also instead of ("\ \ ", use (" \ " ",

```
var str = "{\"PartyCode\":\"99\",\"Name\":\"ooooo\",\"NameEng\":null,\"Note\":null,\"ManagerId\":1,\"ParentId\":null,\"PartyStatusId\":1,\"PartyTypeId\":1,\"CenterInfoId\":4177,\"GovernateInfoId\":321,\"LocationInfoId\":25,\"SectorInfoId\":6,\"SectorGroupInfoId\":36,\"SectorCategroyInfoId\":66,\"MainBranch\":null,\"CoordinateX\":null,\"CoordinateY\":null,\"IssueDate\":\"2022-06-08T00: 00:00\"}";

str = str.Replace("\"", "\\\\\\\"");
```